# nginx X-Frame-Options still with the same value

Tags: php, web-services, magento, nginx

I used

> add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

in nginx but when i removed it; it still with the same value as i can't use iFrame in my website and got below error:

> Refused to display 'xxx' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Removed this configuration and restarted both nginx and php-fpm, tried

> add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOWALL";

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_tokens off;
    access_log  off;
    listen 80 default;
    server_name www.example.com *.example.com; 
    root /var/www/vhosts/example.com;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; 
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; 
        expires 30d; 
      if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php?title=$1&$2 last;
            }
    }

    set $ssl "off";
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "https") {
    set $ssl "on";
    }


    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
         access_log        off;
         log_not_found     off;
         expires           30d;
     }


    location @handler { 
        rewrite / /index.php;
                                   }

    location ~ .php/ { 
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { 
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/example.sock;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; 
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 1024k;
        fastcgi_buffers 512 32k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 1024k;

        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

Found below in the header when checking with inspect element:

```
X-Frame-Options:ALLOW-FROM https://www.youtube.com/
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

So there is X-Frame-Options added somehow but can't find it

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why i got below error even after removing x-frame-options from nginx configuration? 
>Refused to display 'xxx' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: You should post your nginx configuration

Comment: nginx configuration added (add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;) was in the configuration but removed. And still have same error

Comment: Same happening for me. Can't set back from DENY.

Comment: There is no `ALLOWALL` option. see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out for myself. What I did is that when I saw it was not working, I made a quick change in .html file and saved it. After that it worked.

E.g.:
I have a file run on nginx, say, index.html. I removed the `add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;` line in `nginx.conf`, restarted the server, but no luck. It kept denying. It acted as it didn't change at all, while the change WAS there. What I did is, I changed a line (or just add a space. Just make ANY change) in `index.html`, saved the change, and restarted the server and... voila: worked!

Comment: I came across this issue, NGINX showed that the header option was set to deny but still served the page inside iFrames. I edited the index.html and restarted nginx and it suddenly worked. Hope someone can weigh in on this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that nginx serves a cached version of the file until it detects any changes in the file, and the headers are already attached in the cached version.